# Installing spell-checking extension in portable LibreOffice fails

Tags: windows-10, libreoffice-writer, spell-check, portable-apps, extension

I had an issue with a German document being opened in portable LibreOffice using Windows 10:
Writer complained that the spelling module was missing, but when I tried to install the extension, it always failed, whether I tried for "current user only" or "for all users".
There was no specific useful error message, however.

Eventually I found out that I have to close the document; then the extension installed without a problem!

AFAIR I never had such problem with the non-portable version, but I'm not 100% sure.

Can anybody explain what's going on in the portable version?

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense as installed plugins aren't really meant to be used with portable apps. I don't think you can do a lot here, except trying to find steps to install it for the portable version.

Comment: Well, if a hyphenation module for a language is missing, any document with hyphenation would look significantly different (words aren't hyphenated) then. One could argue a lot, but if such basic features don't work, the whole portable apps concept is rather useless IMHO.

Comment: Did you try checking how to install extensions on portable version? E.g. https://portableapps.com/node/64771 Changing user profile location in settings could be sufficient.

Comment: @Destroy666 Of course I was using the extension manager, assuming it knows where to put things and how to register the extension. Could it be a lack of Java (none found)?

Comment: Maybe it does know but still puts it in a non-portable location if you have wrong setup. Did you verify where your settings point? I doubt it's Java related but I don't know what the extension requires under the hood.

Comment: @Destroy666 Can you explain what you mean with "Did you verify where your settings point?"?